# How to while loop exception in Python

Tags: python

Someone said to me that I need to convert my code below to while or for loops.

```py
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

def edit_button(max_sec=10):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]")))
        print("detected")
    except:
        driver.refresh()
        max_sec -= 1
        print(max_sec)
        if max_sec == 0:
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
        print("not detected")

        edit_button(max_sec)

edit_button()
```

The code above means that if edit button is not detected, then refresh until it appears for maximum of 10 seconds.

I tried to convert it to while loops, but it shows EXCEPTION ERROR. because this is not detected:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]")))
```

Here is my while loop:

```py
max_sec = 10
while not WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]"))):
    driver.refresh()
    max_sec -= 1
    print(max_sec)
    if max_sec == 0:
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
        sys.exit()
        
print("success")
```

How to make something like this:

```py
while element is exception:
```

Thanks sorry I am new to Python.

Comment: This question might benefit from more context. It may be helpful to provide the package that you are using. Why would your edit button not be detected? What you're trying to do is block your code from running until the edit button is detected (with a timeout period), but I would expect that if the package requires blocking then it will offer some blocking method that blocks the main process until the edit button is created. Are you following a tutorial? Did you write the package yourself? These questions would be best answered in an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change loop condition and catch exception normally with `try/except` inside loop.

Here is the example:

```py
seconds_left = 10

while seconds_left != 0:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]"),
            ),
        )
        break
    except:
        seconds_left -= 1
        driver.refresh()

if seconds_left == 0:
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
    sys.exit()

print("success")
```